# From Excel to WordPress site app

Tags: database, wordpress, excel

I am searching for the proper way to build an online database application to behave similar to an Excel datasheets that I have.

I have a working excel file with many calculations, and I need to port this to my WordPress  website as a service.

My clients would be able to log into the web app section in WordPress, and manipulate their own data sheet, and get results from all the calculations.

Any idea or direction regarding recommended platform or programming language that can do that ?

Sincerely

Dan

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58374/12615)

Comment: Oh, sure, please take the [**Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the guide **[ask]** before posting another question or updating this one to make it on-topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a web calculators based on an Excel file I would recommend you to take a look at “[Appizy](http://appizy.com)”. It converts instantly a spreadsheet into a standalone web calculation tool (HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT). You don’t need to hardcode the whole interface and calculation formulas!

As your Excel file is converted in HTML you can download it and paste it in your WP installation.

If you want to include database you might need to had a bit of PHP on top...

Let me know if it helped you!